# How to open TensorBoard from datalab when proxy port number indicated

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-datalab

I’m using a python notebook in gGloud datalab to re-train a neural network.

From the notebook I call retrain.py with

```
!python -m retrain --bottleneck_dir=../tf_files/bottlenecks --how_many_training_steps=500 --model_dir=../tf_files/models/ --summaries_dir=../tf_files/training_summaries/'mobilenet_1.0_224' --output_graph=../tf_files/retrained_graph.pb --output_labels=../tf_files/retrained_labels.txt --architecture='mobilenet_1.0_224' --image_dir=../tf_files/flower_photos
```

Within retrain.py I import the Tensorboard with

```
from google.datalab.ml import TensorBoard as tb
```

followed by the main function that does a bunch of things for the training process followed by:

```
inti=tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
tb.start('./tmp/retrain_logs’)
```

Executing retrain.py, a neural network will be trained, and TensorBoard will be activated (as stated in the output of my notebook copied below)

> TensorBoard 1.8.0 at http://3439c553be9b:59199 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
>   {'text/html':TensorBoard was started successfully with pid 7707. Click here to access it.}

I tried to see the TensorBoard by:

1. clicking on the link provided (http://3439c553be9b:59199). A site on my web-brower opens but is empty.
2. I used gCloud Shell to connect with 'datalab connect --port=59199 .' This brings me to my files on gCloud, but not to a TensorBoard.

Can someone tell me how to access the TensorBoard please?

Thank you, 
Julia

Answer (score 0):

Just clicking on the link should work.

Could you check to see if you have a firewall rule that is preventing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the first string "TensorBoard 1.8.0 at http://3439c553be9b:59199 (Press CTRL+C to quit) " was output by the new tensorboard version. The direct link won't work.

The second string "TensorBoard was started successfully with pid 7707. Click here to access it.", the word "here" should be backed up by a hyperlink. See code https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/blob/master/google/datalab/ml/_tensorboard.py#L73. That link should work. Do you get that link?